# Python Problem i am preparing myself for PCEP Exam

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
my_list = [x * x for x in range(5)]

def fun(lst):
    del lst[lst[2]]
    return lst

print(fun(my_list))
```

why is the answer `[0,1,4,9]`

As far as what I understand :
first part :

```
0*0 
1*1
2*2
3*3
4*4
```

so it looks like `[0,1,4,9,16]`
what happens then

Comment: `lst[2]` is `4`, so `del lst[lst[2]]` is doing `del lst[4]` and the last element is deleted.

Comment: comment out the `del` line and in its place print `lst[2]` and then print `lstlist[[2]]`

Answer (score 0):

You define a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [x * x for x in range(5)]
```

This will generate a list containing the squares of the numbers from 0 to 4.
So, my_list will be:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

You have a function fun(lst):

```
def fun(lst):
    del lst[lst[2]]
    return lst
```

This function takes a list as an argument and deletes an element from it.

To understand which element is being deleted:

- First, it accesses the third element of the list (index 2): lst[2].
- For the my_list list, the third element (index 2) is 4.
- Then, it deletes the element at index 4 from the list using del lst[lst[2]].
  So, it will remove the element 16 from my_list.

Finally, when you call fun(my_list), it will modify my_list to:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

So the code creates a list of the squares of numbers from 0 to 4 and then removes the last element of the list using the fun function.